# How to enforce changing homepage of Internet Explorer?

Tags: windows-7, browser, internet-explorer

So, my friend installed some super awesome free game which he totally enjoys playing. But when installing it, he checked "change my home page to superawesomegames.com"

Now whenever he opens the IE, he is directed to the homepage of the game. I tried to change the home page in IE settings, but after a restart, the gaming home page appears.

So far, I found solution in tweaking the shortcut on the desktop to `"iexplore.exe" desiredhomepage.com` which opens IE and loads the desired home page.

However, I would like to do better change. I know that probably uninstalling the game and installing it again would solve my problems, but my friend does not want to lose all his gaming records (which uninstall claims to do)

Is there for instance system registry I could change to enforce default homepage to something my friend wants?

P.S.: Recommending other browser is also not an option, since my friend is very conservative as of internet browser choice

Comment: Performing a reset on IE will help, but I will be honest, it sounds like your friend install malware along with that program.  Only way to solve this problem is to remove the malware.

Comment: Super Awesome Malware!